# Store Files programmatically Windows phone 7 & 8

Tags: file, windows-phone, storage, directory, isolatedstorage

I need to store some backup file to external storage like SD Cards or Email. And later user can restore that backup files.

I've surfed a google lot but what I found is sending email with attachment is not possible. and SD Card is access is also readonly. So Is there any way to store data which still can be accessible after user uninstall the app.

Skydrive & Dropbox is there but what if there is no data connection. So offline solution is what I'm looking for.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Your only offline option is to store data in 'IsolatedStorage' - have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the data in the **IsolatedStorage** until an internet connection is available and back it up then. Users will love you for offering SkyDrive and DropBox backup. That is the way you should go!

There is no way to save data offline even if an App gets uninstalled on Windows Phone. That is part of the sandbox priciple.